# One to many merge using Akka streams

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have a use case where I have a list of values to be fetched from the database and a list of dates for which the values need to be fetched. I want to use akka streams (Flow or Source with GraphDSL) to make a one to many (or many to one) relationship between them so that I fetch each value for each of the dates

For example,

animals = cow, goat, sheep

years=2018, 2019

expected stream output is

cow & 2018

goat & 2018

sheep & 2018

cow & 2019

goat & 2019

sheep & 2019

Answer (score 1):

If you want a product like this, you don't need the Graph DSL.

```
def animalsAndYears(animals: Source[Animal, NotUsed], years: Source[Year, NotUsed]): Source[(Animal, Year), NotUsed] =
  years.flatMapConcat { year =>
    animals.map { animal =>
      animal -> year
    }
  }
```

So:

```
 animalsAndYears(Source(listOfAnimals), Source(listOfYears))
```

would give you a stream of `animal`, `year` tuples.  Let's say that you have a function:

```
 def queryDBForAnimalYear(aandy: (Animal, Year)): Future[Seq[Row]] = ???
```

Then you can get a stream of the rows with:

```
val parallelism: Int = ??? // How many queries to have in-flight at a time
animalsAndYears(Source(listOfAnimals), Source(listOfYears))
  .mapAsync(parallelism) { params => queryDBForAnimalYear(params) }
  .mapConcat(identity)  // gives you a Source[Row]
```